# Sinch Android chatt app Bug

Tags: android, parse-platform, unsatisfiedlinkerror, sinch

I'm working on Android chat app and everything was going fine. I've managed to add users to the parse database and display users on a friends fragment.

But then came Sinch. I added the SDK to my project as instructed on their website and added a service class which I've declared in the manifest like:

```
<service android:name=".services.MessageService" />
```

inside the application tag.

However I am experiencing a fatal error. The app runs fine until I run the service.

I run the service the moment the user logs in or registers successfully, also when already logged in. I think I have an idea of what's happening.

Something to do with:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.landagmail.josemaria.chatapp-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib,
>   /system/lib]]]

When creating the sinch client.

I think it has something to do with Android not finding some kind of library? A sinch one? (`UnsatisfiedLinkError`)

Any help would be greatly appreciated =) Regards, Jose Maria Landa

Here's the output:

> 06-14 20:30:26.052  21498-21498/com.landagmail.josemaria.chatapp
>   E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.landagmail.josemaria.chatapp, PID: 21498
>       java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.landagmail.josemaria.chatapp-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib,
>   /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libsinch-android-rtc.so"
>               at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:366)
>               at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:989)
>               at com.sinch.android.rtc.internal.client.DefaultSinchClient.(DefaultSinchClient.java:72)
>               at com.sinch.android.rtc.internal.client.InternalSinchClientFactory.createSinchClient(InternalSinchClientFactory.java:17)
>               at com.sinch.android.rtc.DefaultSinchClientBuilder.build(DefaultSinchClientBuilder.java:95)
>               at com.landagmail.josemaria.chatapp.services.MessageService.startSinchClient(MessageService.java:45)
>               at com.landagmail.josemaria.chatapp.services.MessageService.onStartCommand(MessageService.java:34)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2893)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:147)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1394)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

forgot it. i solved it. the jniLbis folder was in the wrong directory. should have been in src directory not alongside libs